# I can't get the information I need out with beautifulsoup for my example sentence grabber with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing

I've been trying to make a simple function using beautiful soup to pull all the example sentences off of a website called Tangorin given a single Japanese book. I've tried to write two different types of functions to pull out this data and I just can't get it to work.Sorry this is a long question but I've tried a few things which don't work I have only been coding for a 3 weeks. The data structure I'm trying to pull looks like this:

[image: Data Structure]

Below here is the data structure for one of the sentences on the page for the word 英語 as the search term, web page [https://tangorin.com/sentences?search=英語](https://tangorin.com/sentences?search=%E8%8B%B1%E8%AA%9E).

I'm trying to pull off all of the sentences on the page into a list of the separate sentences. Each sentence is inside a  block like below and I've highlighted out the key information I'm trying to look for.

```
**<div class="entry entry-border sentences undefined ">**
   <div class="entry-menu-wrap">
      <button class="entry-menu-btn btn">
         <svg class="icon" role="img" alt="" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
            <use xlink:href="#icon-chevron-down">
            </use>
         </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
  <dt class="s-jp" lang="ja">
      <a href="/words?search=話 %23n">
        <ruby>
           **話**
           <rt class="roma">hanashi</rt>
        </ruby>
      </a>
      <a href="/words?search=を %23part">
        <ruby>
           **を**
           <rt class="roma">wo</rt>
        </ruby>
      </a>
      <a href="/words?search=為る %23v">
        <ruby>
          **する**
          <rt class="roma">suru</rt>
        </ruby>
      </a>
      <a href="/words?search=事 %23n">
        <ruby>
           **こと**
           <rt class="roma">koto</rt>
        </ruby>
      </a>
      <a href="/words?search=で %23part">
        <ruby>
           **で**
           <rt class="roma">de</rt>
        </ruby>
      </a>
      <a href="/words?search=自分 %23n">
        <ruby>
           **自分**
           <rt class="roma">jibun</rt>
        </ruby>
      </a>
      <a href="/words?search=を %23part">
        <ruby>
           **を**
           <rt class="roma">wo</rt>
        </ruby>
      </a>
      <ruby>
         **曝け出す**
         <rt class="roma">曝kedasu</rt>
      </ruby>
      <a href="/words?search=事 %23n">
        <ruby>
           **こと**
           <rt class="roma">koto</rt>
        </ruby>
      </a>
      <a href="/words?search=を %23part">
        <ruby>
           **を**
           <rt class="roma">wo</rt>
        </ruby>
      </a>
      <a href="/words?search=恐れる %23v">
        <ruby>
           **恐れず**
           <rt class="roma">osorezu</rt>
        </ruby>
      </a>
      **、**
      <a href="/words?search=英語 %23n">
        <mark>
          <ruby>
             **英語**
             <rt class="roma">eigo</rt>
          </ruby>
        </mark>
      </a>
      <a href="/words?search=で %23part">
        <ruby>
           **で**
           <rt class="roma">de</rt>
        </ruby>
      </a>
      <a href="/words?search=他人 %23n">
        <ruby>
           **他人**
           <rt class="roma">tanin</rt>
        </ruby>
      </a>
      <a href="/words?search=と %23part">
        <ruby>
           **と**
           <rt class="roma">to</rt>
        </ruby>
      </a>
      <a href="/words?search=喋る %23v">
        <ruby>
           **しゃべる**
           <rt class="roma">shaberu</rt>
        </ruby>
      </a>
      <a href="/words?search=有らゆる %23pn-adj">
        <ruby>
           **あらゆる**
           <rt class="roma">arayuru</rt>
        </ruby>
      </a>
      <a href="/words?search=機会 %23n">
        <ruby>
           **機会**
           <rt class="roma">kikai</rt>
        </ruby>
      </a>
      <a href="/words?search=を %23part">
        <ruby>
           **を**
           <rt class="roma">wo</rt>
        </ruby>
      </a>
      <a href="/words?search=捕らえる %23v">
        <ruby>
          **とらえ**
          <rt class="roma">torae</rt>
        </ruby>
      </a>
      <a href="/words?search=なさる %23v">
        <ruby>
           **なさい**
           <rt class="roma">nasai</rt>
        </ruby>
      </a>
      **。**
      <a href="/words?search=そうすれば %23adv">
        <ruby>
           **そうすれば**
           <rt class="roma">sousureba</rt>
        </ruby>
      </a>
      <a href="/words?search=直に %23n">
        <ruby>
            **じきに**
            <rt class="roma">jikini</rt>
        </ruby>
      </a>
      <a href="/words?search=形式張る %23n">
        <ruby>
           **形式張らない**
           <rt class="roma">keishikiharanai</rt>
        </ruby>
      </a>
      <a href="/words?search=会話 %23n">
        <ruby>
           **会話**
           <rt class="roma">kaiwa</rt>
        </ruby>
      </a>
      <a href="/words?search=の %23part">
        <ruby>
            **の**
            <rt class="roma">no</rt>
        </ruby>
      </a>
      <a href="/words?search=場面 %23n">
        <ruby>
           **場面**
           <rt class="roma">bamen</rt>
        </ruby>
      </a>
      <a href="/words?search=で %23part">
        <ruby>
           **で**
           <rt class="roma">de</rt>
        </ruby>
      </a>
      <a href="/words?search=気楽 %23n">
        <ruby>
           **気楽**
           <rt class="roma">kiraku</rt>
        </ruby>
      </a>
      <a href="/words?search=に %23part">
        <ruby>
           **に**
           <rt class="roma">ni</rt>
        </ruby>
      </a>
      <a href="/words?search=慣れる %23v">
        <ruby>
           **なれる**
           <rt class="roma">nareru</rt>
        </ruby>
      </a>
      <a href="/words?search=である %23aux-v">
        <ruby>
           **であろう**
           <rt class="roma">dearou</rt>
        </ruby>
      </a>
      **。**
  </dt>
```

So what the problem is inside the class the data I want is stored in one of 3 ways, inside an a=href hyperlink, and then further in a ruby abbreviation. Or in a ruby abbreviation that isn't inside an a=href, or just sometimes in a plain text line in the case of "、", "。", "?" etc.

So I wrote the following code with a lot of help from my friend using beautiful Soup:

```
# all of your sentences from anki deck
# also new sentences will go here
ALL_SENTENCES = set()


# This piece of code returns true if char is in the set of all roman letters
# and false if not
def is_english(char):
    lower_case = ord("a") <= ord(char) <= ord("z")
    upper_case = ord("A") <= ord(char) <= ord("Z")
    return lower_case or upper_case


# This piece of code is to take a random Japanese word from a file and
# generate a Tangorin URL to the page of example
# sentencese for that word
def make_url(word):
    return f"https://tangorin.com/sentences?search={word}"


# This function searches through all of the descendants that have been added into the total
def filter_jap(sentences):
    jap_only = [
        [word for word in sentence if not is_english(word[0])] for sentence in sentences
    ]
    for sentence in jap_only:
        as_string = "".join(sentence) + "\n"
        print(as_string)


def get_random_sentence(all_sentences):
    return random.choice(all_sentences)


def get_example_sentences(word):
    url = make_url(word)
    source = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")
    all_sentences = []
    curr_sentence = ""
    for sentence in soup.findAll(
        "div", class_="entry entry-border sentences undefined"
    ):
        character_blocks = sentence.dt
        for desc in character_blocks.descendants:
            # end of sentence detected, add curr sentence to all sentence list
            # and reset curr sentence
            if desc == "。":
                all_sentences.append(curr_sentence)
                curr_sentence = ""
            # if character is non-english (japanese) add it to current sentence
            elif type(desc) == NavigableString and not is_english(desc[0]):
                curr_sentence += desc
    return all_sentences

def gen_example_sentence(word):
    all_sentences = get_example_sentences(word)
    random_choice = get_random_sentence(all_sentences)
    return(random_choice)

with open('Japanese Words.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for line in f:
        x = gen_example_sentence(line)
        print(x)`
```

The problem with this code is when it comes up against a block like this:

```
  <ruby>
         **曝け出す**
         <rt class="roma">曝kedasu</rt>
      </ruby>
```

Here the item in the rt class of the ruby abbreviation is incorrectly formatted with a Japanese character at the beginning so the for loop comprehension which parses through descendants of navigablestring type that start with an English character completely fails here. So I tried to go a different approach with string manipulation but my coding skills still aren't good enough so it was a serious fail:

```
`def make_url(word):
    return f"https://tangorin.com/sentences?search={word}"

word = "英語"
url = make_url(word)
source = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")
all_sentences = []
curr_sentence = ""
for sentence in soup.findAll("div", class_="entry entry-border sentences undefined"):
    y = sentence.dt
    for line in y:
        if str(type(line)) == "<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>":
            x = str(line.ruby)
            block = str(x.split('<'))
            block = str(block.split('>'))
            print(block)[3]
        #else:
            #curr_sentence += line
        #print(curr_sentence)
        #curr_sentence = ""`
```

I don't know how to go about fixing this issue to pull out the exact information I need to successfully recompile the sentences and then add them into a set of strings.

For some extra Japanese based knowledge, Japanese sentences have no spaces between the characters apart from where spaces are built into some characters like '、' '。' '「' '」'

Also the ruby tags are something called a ruby abbreviation which is a way of describing the position of a Japanese character and the way you read it with english characters above it. The "roma" stands for romaji which means english character readings for Japanese words

Sorry this is such a long question but I have watched a ton of youtube videos on beautifulsoup and other parsing methods and I just can't figure out this issue

Also just in case the **bold** isn't working, inside the xml block the stuff in the ** ** indicators is the bits I want to pull out. Essentially what I want is the stuff inside the ruby abbreviations but not in the rt class, and I also want those plain text items "、", "。" etc. If you run the original descendants code you'll get 99% accurate sentences to see what sort of output I want is. Thank you in advance for anyone whose helping!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract tags with english words first and then use `.get_text()`.

For example (I hope the output is correct, I can't read Japanese):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://tangorin.com/sentences?search=%E8%8B%B1%E8%AA%9E'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

for s in soup.select('.sentences'):
    soup.select_one('.s-en').extract()
    for r in s.select('.roma'):
        r.extract()
    print(s.get_text(strip=True))
```

Prints:

```
私の母はあまり英語が上手に話せない。
２、３ページの英語を訳すのに２時間以上もかかりました。
こんなに上手に英語で手紙を書けるのにどうして話せないの？
英語のコミュニティでお名前とコメントを拝見し、プロフィールを拝読しました。
誰か英語を話す人はいますか。
「未来形」というのは存在しない、ということは受験英語でも一般的になりつつあります。
「順路→」といったかんじの看板を設置したいと思うんですけど、これを英語で作るとどうなるでしょうか？
この表現は日本語にはない英語の比喩表現として、私は大変気に入っています。
英語を学習する上で不可欠な、不規則動詞の活用。
中学生が英語を学ぶ際の最難関の一つが関係代名詞です。
TOEICの学習に限らず、英語を学ぶのであれば英和辞典は必携の書の一つでしょう。
アフィ狙いの釣り記事ですね。英語関係のコミュのあちこちにマルチポストしています。
まるでそれが正しい英語の証左かのように。
「まがりなりにも通じている」ということと「正しい英語を使っている」ということには雲泥の差があります。
上級者が英語力（特に読解力）をつけたければ、語彙を増やすのが王道ですね。
その当時、どこの公立の学校にもネイティブの英語の先生などいませんでした。
彼女は兄に勝るとも劣らぬくらい英語が上手だ。
彼女は英語を話すのが得意で、兄に勝るとも劣らぬくらいだ。
日本では、英語から日本語（英日）、日本語から英語（日英）への翻訳が多く、日西、西日の実需があまりありません。
英語には８つの主な品詞があります：名詞、動詞、形容詞、副詞、代名詞、前置詞、接続詞そして感嘆詞。
ちなみに私は英語がからきし駄目なんです。
話をすることで自分を曝け出すことを恐れず、英語で他人としゃべるあらゆる機会をとらえなさい。そうすればじきに形式張らない会話の場面で気楽になれるであろう。
鈴木先生は私たちに英語を教えてくれる。
例えば、君は英語が好きですか。
良い英語と、悪い英語はどのようにして区別できますか。
```